# How to utilize the native docker image "ca.org1.example.com" to issue identities for my busines network?

Tags: ldap, hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger-fabric-ca

I am using Hyperledger Fabric 1.2.1, I deployed my network and need to integrate it with LDAP server, for that, I am trying to integrate my application with the built-in ca.org1.example docker container.

When I start my fabric with "startFabric.sh" the image stats well and I have it Listening on http://0.0.0.0:7054 however when I use fabric-ca-client command:
./fabric-ca-client enroll -u http://admin:adminpw@localhost:7054
I am able to enroll, but after that when I attempt to do the following command:
./fabric-ca-client affiliation list
I am getting an error that:
"Error: Response from server: Error Code: 20 - Authorization failure"

Any idea how to go further for this integration?

Answer (score 0):

`http://admin:adminpw@localhost:7054` this means you are enrolling as the CA administrator in order to interact with CA server

when you try to use the client identity after you authenticate it gives error means you have not authenticate properly

try to use my below code snippets

```
   export FABRIC_CA_CLIENT_HOME=$HOME/cas/$CA_NAME
   export FABRIC_CA_CLIENT_TLS_CERTFILES={If CA has TLS enabled pass tls cert file location}
   fabric-ca-client enroll -d -u https://admin:adminpw@$CA_HOST:7054
```

Now proceed for listing affliations